# Phonegap App hangs with bad internet connection

Tags: javascript, cordova

My app works fine with and without an internet connection, as all the js files are local.
But when there is a bad internet connection, the app just hangs.
Why is that? And is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please cross check that have you made all js and css files local.You may forget to make css files local.Hope my answer will help to solve your problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had a unused url that was looking for an internet connection. After removing this, it all worked fine